# Using p5.js, is it possible to preload some .json files that are defined in a .json file that is itself preloaded with the preload() function?

Tags: javascript, json, p5.js

I am working on a ***p5.js*** project that loads some configuration options from a JSON file. I am preloading the config file in p5.js's `preload()` function, like so:

```
let config = {};

function preload() {
    config = loadJSON("data/config.json");
}
```

Part of the config JSON file contains some `song` objects that each have a `filename` property that is another JSON file I would like to preload:

```
"songs": [
    {
        "title": "Song One",
        "filename": "01.json"
    },
    ...
]
```

I cannot access the config file data before p5.js's `setup()` function (as I cannot guarantee the config file has been completely read until then), by which time I can no longer preload the song JSON files.

I'm trying to figure out if there's any way around this.

**EDIT**: Thanks to George's answer below, I have it working as below. The following all runs before entering p5.js's `setup()` function, which is exaclty what I was after:

```
let config = {};

function preload() {
    config = loadJSON("config.json", configLoaded);
}

function configLoaded(_config) {
    let songs_length = _config.album.songs.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < songs_length; i++) {
        loadJSON("data/" + _config.album.songs[i].filename, songLoaded);
    }
}

function songLoaded(_song) {
    console.log(_song);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to load [loadJSON()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadJSON) and setup the callbacks for when the data is either loaded or errors.

Hopefully, if everything is setup neatly, something as simple as this should work:

```
function preload() {
    config = loadJSON("data/config.json");
    loadJSON(config.songs[0].filename,songOneLoaded);
}

function songOneLoaded(data){
    console.log("song one data loaded",data);
}
```

**Note** I can't test the above, but hopefully it helps point you in the right direction. I would also double check the paths to the .json files to load. Ideally you'd always be handling the error case as well.

Comment: Thanks, George - you showed me how to think about it a little differently and I have it working now. I made an edit to my question to show how I did it.

Comment: No problem! Great to see you've got it working. Bare in mind you're re-using the same callback for all songs. Next step might be populating a list of songs as they load. Best of luck

Comment: Once the config file has loaded, I'm creating an array of `Song` objects. Each `Song` object takes the filename as an argument to it's constructor, and preloads it's own JSON file during the array creation loop :)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add it to the `preload()` function? Something like this:

```
let config = {};
let songOne = 

function preload() {
    config = loadJSON("data/config.json");
    let songOneUrl = config.songs[0].filename;
    songOne = loadSongFile(songOneUrl);
}
```

The above is just an example, and the syntax is probably not right (I'm not sure how you're loading the songs). But the idea should be the same.

**Edit:** I just saw that George answered this a few seconds before me. I'd take his word over mine.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid explicitly preloading the song JSON files from `preload()` as the different config files I'm using will include a variable number of songs. Ideally, I like to have a bunch of config files and simply rename the one I need to `config.json` so I don't have to touch the JavaScript at all. George's answer pointed me in the right direction and I have it working now, but thanks for your response.